# SimpleDateFormat.parse generating inconsistent results

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat

I am using SimpleDateFormat to parse a string to DateTime, as shown in the code below.

```
val formatSrc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
formatSrc.setLenient(false)
val temp = formatSrc.parse("2017-02-04T09:55:42.000Z")
print(temp)
```

The results should be 
`Sat Feb 04 09:55:42 UTC 2017`
, however I get inconsistent result, for example, it could be below `Tue Feb 04 00:00:04 UTC 2200`, or `Wed Feb 04 09:55:42 UTC 2201`, or some other things. 
BTW, I am using Scala with Spark to process some text data.
any idea why?

Comment: When you say "inconsistent", do you mean that your sample code provides different outputs on different runs?

Comment: Why you think that result should be `Sat Feb 04 09:55:42 UTC 2017`? You use same `formatSrc` for `parse` and for `format`.

Comment: @BobDalgleish yes.

Comment: @talex Oh, sorry. I updated my question. My original idea is validating that the input in the desired format by format the parsed DateTime and compare with the input.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is *probably* (though can't be sure) a concurrency issue: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe, from its Javadoc:

> Date formats are not synchronized.
>   It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread.
>   If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

Spark obviously uses multiple threads (generally speaking, one per *partition*)- if those threads share the same `SimpleDateFormat` instance, that would explain the behavior you're seeing.

To fix this - use a different thread-safe formatter, or create a separate formatter per record / partition.

Comment: But this specific code is tread-safe because it create new instance of `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I think Tzach's answer makes sense. I did not create a separate instance for each thread. So it should be multi-threading problem as Spark is obviously multi-threaded.     I replaced with a Joda DateTimeFormat, which is thread-safe. Then problem is solved.     http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: @talex I _guessed_ the "minimal" code example was made a bit too minimal, leaving out the part where the single instance was used inside a Spark transformation (thus concurrently) - and apparently I guessed right (I've seen this issue before)

Answer (score 1):

Set the timezone to UTC (GMT) on the formatter otherwise the trailing "Z" which you have escaped (hence wrongly interpreting as literal) cannot be understood as UTC+00:

```
formatSrc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

**Attention:** If you want to compare the parsed result with the method `print(temp)` then I fear that you are just implicitly using the `Date`-method `toString()` which uses a completely different format (in your default timezone).

Answer (score 0):

I think Tzach's answer makes sense. I did not create a separate instance for each thread. So it should be multi-threading problem as Spark is obviously multi-threaded.     I replaced with a Joda DateTimeFormat, which is thread-safe. Then problem is solved.     http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: "did not create a separate instance for each thread" - well, this is not what you have shown in your question as code (where you explicitly create a new instance). So you should better have posted a minimal but complete and compilable demo. Nevertheless, it is not the only mistake, see my answer.

Comment: An answer saying another answer is correct is... not really how this goes, is it? Why post another answer instead of accepting / upvoting the original one? :/

Comment: This is my first post on StackOverFlow  :)

Comment: You have posted the same as an appropriate and welcome comment under the answer, so the good thing to do now will be to delete the answer that isn't an answer. You should have a delete link under your own answer. @PatrickYodoshi

Answer (score 0):

Your date-time format fits an ISO 8601 instant exactly. The modern Java date & time API work so well with ISO 8601. So I suggest you use it.

I am sorry I cannot write Scala code, so you will have to translate from Java:

```
    Instant temp = Instant.parse("2017-02-04T09:55:42.000Z");
```

Advantages:

- You have skipped the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes and have begun using their modern replacement.
- It’s one line instead of three and expresses your intent more clearly.
- Parsing is thread safe, so if Tzach Zohar has guessed correctly, it solves your issue.